# Check if value of current cell matches value of previous cell

Tags: excel

I need to create a conditional that prints "Success" when there are two pass values consecutively in column A. If there aren't two consecutive pass values it should print "Try Again".

```
   A        B
1 Fail   Try Again
2 Fail
3 Pass
```

---

```
   A        B
1 Fail   Try Again
2 Fail
3 Pass
4 Fail
```

---

```
   A        B
1 Fail   Try Again
2 Fail
3 Pass
4 Fail
5 Pass
```

---

```
   A        B
1 Fail   Success
2 Fail
3 Pass
4 Fail
5 Pass
6 Pass
```

I figured I could do something like `=COUNTIF(A1:A6, "Pass")`. For dealing with consecutive passes maybe something like `=IF(A2=A1)`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS with offset ranges:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"Pass",A2:A6,"Pass")>0,"Succeed","Try Again")
```

[image]

Comment: beat me by 7 seconds.  Bah! you are getting too fast

Comment: @ScottCraner - I have to type fast, in my mind I know you're right on my heels or already beating me :-)

Comment: I was going to go with CSE:  `=IF(MATCH(2,(A1:A5="pass")+(A2:A6="pass"),),"Suceed","Try Again")`  Yours is better.

Comment: Filter version: `=IF(ISERROR(FILTER(A1:A100000,(A1:A100000="Pass")*(A2:A100001="Pass"))),"Try Again","Succeed")`

Comment: The `>0` can be implied.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I was waiting for a FILTER version :-)

Comment: @ExcelHero - agreed it can be implied, leaving it explicit so OP can follow the logic more clearly... and in the world of dynamic arrays, I might argue that my version isn't necessarily better, idk.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you :)

```
C1=IF(MAX((A1:A6="pass")+(A2:A7="pass"))=2,"ok","not")
```

or

```
C1=IF(OR((A1:A6="pass")*(A2:A7="pass")),"ok","not")
```

[image]